# Casting and getting values from date picker and time picker in android

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I have a `DatePicker` and a `TimePicker` in my app. Can anyone tell me how to get the values of the date and time that are selected??? What i mean to say is, for `EditText` we can declare as

```
final EditText name = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
```

and we can cast the data of it by using `name.getText().toString()`.

So similarly how can we get the values of DatePicker and TimePicker to a String???

Answer (score 54, accepted):

DatePicker has

```
getYear() 
getMonth() 
getDayOfMonth()
```

to make a Date object from a DatePicker you'd do `new Date(datePicker.getYear() - 1900, datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());`

**Note that this constructor was [deprecated in API level 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29)** - please [refer to andrescanavesi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592499/casting-and-getting-values-from-date-picker-and-time-picker-in-android/14590203#14590203) for a more appropriate way of creating a Date object.

TimePicker has

```
getCurrentHour()
getCurrentMinute()
```

Comment: Can u plz provide an example??? i am getting an error while initializing the date and time objects

Comment: And, for those using Joda, use `new DateTime(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), 0, 0)`

Comment: Although this is a valid way to get the date, `datePicker.getCalendarView().getDate()` is probably a more accurate way of answering the given question; so you would use it as `new Date(datePicker.getCalendarView().getDate())`.

Comment: In case of the time picker, I get the hour and the minute in the form of an integer. So the hour is an `integer` and the minute is an `integer`.

How do I get a date object to store the the time?

Answer (score 28):

I use this:

```
    /**
 * 
 * @param datePicker
 * @return a java.util.Date
 */
public static java.util.Date getDateFromDatePicket(DatePicker datePicker){
    int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = datePicker.getMonth();
    int year =  datePicker.getYear();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);

    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Beware, this will actually set the time of the returned `Date` to the current time, instead of midnight.

Comment: Nice method. But could you add `TimePicker` related code to it? Question is about `DatePicker` + `TimePicker`.

Comment: Add this to include Hours and minutes from Timepicker calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, expDate_hours);                            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, expDate_mins); where expDate_hours and _mins are set in onTimeChanged in the OnTimeChangedListener of your timepicker.

Answer (score 5):

```
date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date_of_birth_textfield);

date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }
        });


        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

updateDisplay();

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id)
        {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);
}
return null
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener= new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("calendar view shown.."+view.getCalendarViewShown());
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
              c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
              c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
              mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                updateDisplay();
           // mMonth = monthOfYear;
           // mDay = dayOfMonth;

        }
    };

private void updateDisplay() {
        date.setText(
                new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 `based` so add 1


                .append(mYear).append("-").append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append(""));
        //date.setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(c.getTime()));

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest looking at the [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) class in android. Be careful to import the DateFormat mentioned in the android docs.
After that, whatever formatting you want to achieve is really simple.
For a basic Aug 12, 2012 you can do this.

```
DatePicker myDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.mydatepicker);
String selectedDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDatePicker.getCalendarView().getDate());
```

Look at the [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) class to get various other configurations.

Comment: This, along with`SimpleDateFormat` which inherits from `DateFormat` are definitely the best and cleanest way IMHO

Answer (score 3):

Combined all the answers and made a code snippet out of it.

Import datePicker on the top of your class:

```
import android.widget.DatePicker;
```

Inside your class declare the following variable:

```
private DatePicker dobPicker;
```

And here is the code to be done in button click event:

```
 dobPicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dobPicker);
        Integer dobYear = dobPicker.getYear();
        Integer dobMonth = dobPicker.getMonth();
        Integer dobDate = dobPicker.getDayOfMonth();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(dobYear.toString()).append("-").append(dobMonth.toString()).append("-").append(dobDate.toString()).append(" 00:00:00");
        String dobStr=sb.toString();
```

Where in R.id.dobPicker, dobPicker is your datePicker in the layout xml file. This gives you a string at the end, which could be stored or sent to the server.

Answer (score 2):

### getDateTimeFromPickers()

**Simple Method for Getting Date and Time from a DatePicker and a TimePicker**

*Caveat: it uses **[JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)**'s [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) as the return. You can modify it to use whatever you like.*

```
 // Gets the Date and Time from a DatePicker and TimePicker and return a JodaTime DateTime from them, in current timezone.
 //
 private DateTime getDateTimeFromPickers( int DatePickerId, int TimePickerId ) {
     DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(DatePickerId);
     TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(TimePickerId);

     String year    = Integer.toString(dp.getYear()) ;
     String month   = StringUtils.leftPad( Integer.toString(dp.getMonth() + 1), 2, "0" );
     String day     = StringUtils.leftPad( Integer.toString(dp.getDayOfMonth()), 2, "0" );
     String hour    = StringUtils.leftPad( Integer.toString(tp.getCurrentHour()), 2, "0" );
     String minutes = StringUtils.leftPad( Integer.toString(tp.getCurrentMinute()), 2, "0" );

     String dateTime = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + hour + ":" + minutes + ":00.000";

     return DateTime.parse(dateTime);
 }
```

Hope that helps.

JP

Answer (score 2):

I would do it as:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(dp.getYear(), dp.getMonth(), dp.getDayOfMonth(), Tp.getCurrentHour(), Tp.getCurrentMinute());
    DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    TimeZone gmtTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
    gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmtTime);
    String mydate = ""+ gmtFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

p.s dp and tp are date pickers and time picker in android.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(myYear).append("-").append(myMonth).append("-").append(myDay);
    String str=sb.toString();
    edittext.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow with Format Ex: 24 December 2014.

```
            DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datepicker_inspection);
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
            String inspectiondate = df.format(new Date(datePicker.getYear() - 1900, datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth()));
```