# Android Java - how to get day of year in DatePicker?

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

This gives me Day of year. But question is how to get day of year from DatePicker.

```
datePicker.getDayOfYear();
```

this doesn't work :(

Comment: Question has been asked many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592499/casting-and-getting-values-from-date-picker-and-time-picker-in-android

Comment: but, I can get getYear() 
getMonth() 
getDayOfMonth(). I want to get day of year...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this java and android code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
```

in your method do this:

```
    Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    localCalendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
    int CurrentDayOfYear = localCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

and finally you can get code from `CurrentDayOfYear`.

Comment: Thanks you! Works very well :-)

Comment: @user2551317 DatePicker is not able to give you day of year. In my example I have used datePicker.getYear() , datePicker.getMonth() and datePicker.getDayOfMonth() as parameters for get Date of Year from Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
int day = calendar.get(DAY_OF_YEAR);

Something along those lines is what I think you're looking for. Let me know if you need more help.